# Is there any method to disable logoff,lock and taskmanager in ctrl+alt+del in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

On running my window application. if the user press ctrl+alt+del i need to disable these buttons..is there any method

Comment: You speak about a windows application, but used asp.net in your tags.  Which one is correct ?

Comment: its a window application and its runs on a window server...

Comment: WHAT?? you've tagged `asp.net` and talk about `window application`...? just to mention it: do you know the difference between client- and server-side?

Comment: if your app does this, it would most certainly be blocked as a virus!

Comment: What version of Windows are you targeting? In XP, you need to write your own replacement for `msgina.dll`. That's been replaced as of Windows Vista. I can give you better advice if you add some clarifying details to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not disabled them, but maybe you like to disable the task manager, and or the lock down.

```
Disable Lock Workstation button:
Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Key: Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System 
Name: DisableLockWorkstation 
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1 disable

Disable Task Manager button: 
Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Key: Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System 
Name: DisableTaskMgr
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1 disable
```

Also you can consider

```
Disable Change Password button: 
Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Key: Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System 
Name: DisableChangePassword 
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1 disable

Disable Logoff button: 
Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Key: Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer Note: change from System to Explorer
Name: NoLogoff
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1 disable
```

Comment: Do note that you've suggested editing the Registry. That had better not be something an application does on my computer without my permission!

Comment: thanks it worked well.. and on-form closing need to change all these back to default values, i agree editing the registry is not a good method.But is there any other simple method to avoid it..

Comment: i am using windows XP,,,the above mentioned method of editing the registry is worse hack to be used.But as far from search i didn't find any solution.All i could find was rewriting the Gina.dll but it is really hard part i cannot ruin windows since it doesn't come free.

Comment: @deepu: That doesn't make any sense. If you somehow corrupt your Windows installation, you can just reinstall it. You don't have to buy a new copy every time. If you're doing this for your own computer, feel free to edit the Registry. But then you should have asked this question on Super User. This is not the recommended way of implementing this. Whining about how hard it is to do things the right way isn't really a solution, either. There's [an article in MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx) on customizing GINA.

Comment: I understand that the negative is because some one say that is not good to edit this registry values... Well ether a programmer make responsible programs that do the correct work, ether make craps. To edit or not the registry values is a little critical to be car foul not to break anything - the same think like the file.delete(*).

Answer (score 10):

I certainly hope not - the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> key combination is intercepted by the operating system and is never passed to applications. This is a security measure: if the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd>, it is *guaranteed* that what the user will see is the login screen / task manager (depending on which Windows version you have), not some application that tries to steal his password (I'm not implying that that's your intention, but such applications are what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> is designed to prevent).

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, CTRL-ALT-DEL is the only key combination you can't override.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same question. I had to not let the user having access to the `Ctrl+Alt+Del` functionality. I did find a workaround to disable them.
I changed the keyboard mapping inside the registry. As removing the `Ctrl-Alt-Del` functionality can be dangerous, I just switch the `Alt` key by the `ScrollLock` key.
To do so, you will need to add the following registry key (see this [website](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/) for more explanation, you can find the keyboard scan code everywhere if you want to change the ScrollLock by another key [but here a link](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html)):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout

Key Name: Scancode Map
Type: Binary
Value to enter: 
00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 
03 00 00 00 => represent the number of keys you are modifying + 1 (for some reason, mapping to another key is not counting as 1)
00 00 38 00 => Left-Alt key is 38 00 so here we give 00 00 (nothing) to the Left-Alt key. It will disable it.
38 00 46 00 => ScrollLock key is 46 00 so here we give the Left-Alt key functionality to our ScrollLock key. ScrollLock will be Alt key now.
00 00 38 E0 => Right-Alt key is 38 E0 so here we give 00 00 (nothing) to the Right-Alt key. It will disable it.
00 00 00 00 => Terminator
```

Hope it helps one of you! You will just need to register this key in your application but be aware that it will impact the entire system!